# Why do we keep referring to the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle in situations that we don't - and can't - know about?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, singularities

In all of my reading in physics, I have been surprised by the number of times that I read "this can't exist" or "that can't exist" because of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.  Every time it comes up, I am left to wonder "has anybody actually tested it in this (or that) particular instance? Or are we just making an assumption based on a 100 year old theory?"

This morning I read [this article about singularities](https://bigthink.com/13-8/physics-math-singularity/) and I am left thinking how the heck can we claim that because of the HUP, a singularity can't exist at the centre of a black hole.  Obviously the physics inside a black hole is very complex and currently beyond our understanding.

I realize that we can rely on the HUP in our day to day lives working at CERN.   But is it not a stretch to make this claim about black holes? Do we have enough evidence about the HUP to say that we can rely on it as truth, even in these extreme situations?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want as an answer to this question. Are you asking about any specific claim in the article you linked? Alas, why you'd expect an article on "bigthink.com" to be scientifically rigorous is beyond me in the first place - there isn't really any scientifically precise claim *there* one could criticize (it's also saying things like *"Here, gravity itself goes to infinity."*, which is perhaps acceptable for math-free pop-science, but a very poor turn of phrase when you actually want to be precise).

Comment: In any case, the strange bit about a "100 year old theory" is a strange bit to include in a question on a physics site. The age of a theory has nothing directly to do with its usefulness or applicability, and it reads very much as if you picked a pop-science strawman to construct some distorted picture about what "we" in "physics" do.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What I am asking is in the last sentence of my question: Do we have enough evidence about the HUP to say that we can rely on it as truth, even in these extreme situations?  This is what I am looking for an answer too.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  The article was written by Marcelo Gleiser, a theoretical physicist.  So maybe the magazine isn't the most rigorous, but I'm relying on his explanation.

Comment: Singularities can't exist simply due to the way language works and what it means to say that something is a singularity. It precisely means that our theory predicts non-sensical values (such as infinite curvature) and is thus inadequate to faithfully describe nature in the relevant situation. So singularities are in our theories -- not in nature, by construction.

Comment: @DvijD.C.  I'm not asking about singularities. I'm asking about the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.  Do we have enough evidence about the HUP to say that we can rely on it as truth, even in these extreme situations?

Comment: @foolishmuse I was responding to this part of your post: "I am left thinking how the heck can we claim that because of the HUP, a singularity can't exist at the center of a black hole." Your broader question is impossible to answer because it's not clear what you mean by "rely on it as truth". Do people accept the Heisenberg uncertainty principle as the unchangeable word of God? Obviously not. Can we willy-nilly say "Eh! Maybe it is violated even if don't have a concrete reason to think it should be violated"? Also, obviously no.

Comment: "Do we have enough evidence about the HUP to say that we can rely on it as truth?" --- Which step in the proof of the HUP do you find less than totally convincing?  Do you count it as evidence that many thousands of people have studied this proof and none has found an issue with it?

Comment: This would be my last comment but here's the thing: even if you encounter an uncharted territory like the center of a black hole, etc., you don't just throw away everything you have learned and start making up completely new physics from scratch. If that's not what you are suggesting and your only concern is if physicists are sticking too rigidly to HUP, that's not the case. To give you an example that's on my mind, the commutation relations $[x,p]=i$ that underlie HUP have been suspected to be modified in quantum gravity.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @DvijD.C.  Your comment: "Do people accept the Heisenberg uncertainty principle as the unchangeable word of God? Obviously not."    I think you'd be surprised that every single paper I've read actually does accept the HUP as the unchangeable word of God.  They just toss it into every theory and expect me to accept it as a given.  This is  what has disturbed me so much, and then this morning's paper prompted me  to ask this question.  Thankfully, Anna and Marco have provided me with good reasoning for the wide spread acceptance.

Comment: @foolishmuse:  You might find that every single paper you've read treats the laws of arithmetic as the unchangeable word of God as well.  Does that also trouble you?

Comment: Only Quantum Gravity can tell if HUP still holds in a black hole +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history of the HUP is  spread over time, and since its first proposal the theory of quantum mechanics and quantum field theory have been validated over and over again with myriads of experiments. It can be shown that the commutator relations in the theory of quantum mechanics lead to the HUP, for exampl[e here.](https://people.physics.anu.edu.au/%7Ecms130/phys2013/hup/derivation.htm)

Thus the validation of quantum theory is also a validation, i.e. experimental verification of the HUP.

> Do we have enough evidence about the HUP to say that we can rely on it as truth, even in these extreme situations?

Now cosmological models use quantum mechanics in modeling the early stages of the universe, trying to avoid the singularities of classical mechanics, and the HUP is an envelope, order of magnitude estimate of how with quantum mechanics singularities are avoided. If we invoke quantum mechanics for singularities  we also invoke the HUP.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  The math is beyond me, but I pick up the key meaning:   The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle exists as a fundamental mathematical relationship between two operators that are not compatible. If two observables are compatible, their commutator is zero and thus there is no uncertainty in their measurement. However, if two observables aren't compatible there will be an inherent uncertainty in the measurement. To see that this has physical meaning and is not just a mathematical trick, look at Heisenberg's gamma ray telescope thought experiment.

Answer (score 4):

A key tenet of quantum theory is that the position and momentum of a particle are determined in a probabilistic way by its wave function. The HUP is a mathematical consequence of that- it is not a standalone assumption. So when people say that such and such is not possible because of the HUP, they really mean that it is not possible because of the fundamental implications of quantum theory.

So if someone says that a singularity cannot exist inside a black hole because of the HUP, what they mean is that *if* quantum theory applies at the centre of a black hole then there cannot be a singularity there. Of course, we can't yet prove what happens at the centre of a black hole, so it is all a matter of conjecture.

Comment: Thanks. When I combine it with the link that  Anna V gave, it gives me the complete picture.